# Как прочитать значение Esc[#;#R программно?

Tags: linux

На консоли Linux широко используются команды, записываемые в виде Esc-последовательностей. Подать подобную команду из консольного приложения очень просто, достаточно написать что-то вроде print(screen,"E[6n") и команда "Выдать текущее положение курсора" поступит именно туда, куда надо, а консоль тут же ответит, выведя на экран сообщение - ^[[20;30R - которое начинается как раз в текущей позиции курсора и означает "строка 20, колонка 30".

Но мне нужно перехватить этот доклад консоли так, чтобы на экран он не попал, а осел в какой-либо переменной в моём консольном приложении, чтобы использовать эти данные для организации дальнейшего вывода текста в окне консоли.

Проблема возникла потому, что, если выводить на консоль русский текст в кодировке utf-8, обычные функции вроде get_cursor_position() на двухбайтовой кодировке сбиваются и выводят неверное значение позиции курсора, а Esc-команда выдаёт именно то, что мне надо.

Спасибо!

Comment: А всякие ncurces тут помочь не могут? (я с ними просто дела не имел, поэтому подробнее не напишу). К тому же esc-последовательности специфичны для конкретного терминала и закладываться на них в своей программе не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно 6n у меня возвращает только "колонку"... не знаю, годится ли это Вам, но непосредственно в шеле (bash) работает такой вариант:

```
$~ POSITION="15;25"; RETURN=$(echo -ne "\033[${POSITION}H\033[6n") ; echo ${RETURN}
~> ;25R
```